# Is sneezing before commencing work considered a good or bad omen?

Tags: belief, omens

It is popularly believed that sneezing immediately before commencing any kind of work is a bad omen or it brings unfavorable results, is it really a bad omen or it's actually considered good?

Comment: How is sneezing of one person related with functioning of another product or service or another person or group of persons? People sneeze every single second all around the globe so that should affect sales orders of companies all the time? No export anywhere in the world should be possible when there is sneezing all over the globe, right?

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria This I am seeing in my fellow colleagues for the past 15 years. You may sound right but people's belief I am asking and if it has any support. I do not mind on getting negative votes from you bcoz you people think you are the most intelligent in the universe and underestimate others,

Comment: I'll make it clear. What you said about sneeze is true but it's never applicable directly on daily activities.  It is for different purpose. We people don't have knowledge about it but we assume it as belief system and practice in wrong way. So for your daily activities it's never gonna work. Make sure you worship God in correct manner and with devotion, no obstacles will be there for your activities/works.

Comment: In my case if I'm about to leave my house and someone sneezes right at that time then my elders like mom will ask me to stop for few moments before starting the journey. So, there's a belief that it's a bad omen. @ParthasarathyRaghavan

Comment: @Rickross You are right. Even here we have the same belief. Belief turned into practice.

Comment: @AkshayKumarS Your sentences seems intact. Sneezing bad omen belief turned into practice. Assume an office consisting 75 peoples 70 murmers somebody sneezed this  work will not happen is a mindset which is culminated in their brains and immediately they respond.

Comment: @ParthsarathyRaghavan - that belief is applicable only in certain instances and for individual.  In your case,  its wrong practice.

Comment: It is usually what you yourself believe, something bad for others can be good omen for you. I too used to believe in this but then one day made up my mind to see if actually anything goes wrong but nothing bad happened and every time such thing happened I ignored it and nothing bad ever happened. I have a relative who buys iron stuff on saturdays even though it is considered bad but it suited him as he made profits only if he bought iron stuff on saturdays! I even tried with cats crossing my path surprisingly nothing bad ever happened!

Comment: omens are indicative signs when you're about to do something big, important whether it is a new job, buying property, travel etc. sneezing without having a cold, suddenly, just when you're about to start some non-mundane activity is a sign that you should be careful ahead.

Comment: @Just_Do_It  One or two times t may be ok. Try for the third time when you purchase  propertry.   Probably due to kali's grip things turned favour for you.

Comment: @AkshayKumarS Not in my case.  I am talking about a office consisting of 75 peoples. Pl understand the sentence.

Comment: @Parthasarathy by your case I meant about office only.  I didn't say you particularly

Comment: @AkshayKumarS Ok. Maximum people believe in this.

Comment: I don't think this question belongs to this forum. If you had rather asked whether this claim is true or not, it would have made sense.